# . NET Creating Excel Files

Tags: .net, excel

In my application, I need to generate excel files on the fly. I have an option of using Excel  library. But it is mandatory to have excel installed on the machine.

Is there any other .NET API to generate excel files at runtime which doesn't require excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a file that will open in Excel and is just data, you can output to a .csv file. These usually open in the default spreadsheet program (aka Excel on windows). They are much simpler to generate.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you create Excel files in .NET without having Excel installed.

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC